# Prevent rerender / redrawing of a leafletjs map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am building an indoor heatmap with the awesome `leafletjs` library. On top of that I am using `heatmap.js` for the heatmap itself.

If I zoom in, the heatmap as well as the basemap (leaflet GeoJSON layer) seem to be rerendered and thus aren't visible during the zoom animation.

I am trying to get a gradient, smooth zoom animation. 
Is there any way to let every layer be visible during a zoom animation?

Thanks in advance for any support on this!

Comment: The internal zoom animation features are not well-documented in Leaflet, and developers will sometimes choose not to implement them. So for `heatmap.js` the short answer is "not easily." However, there is the [Leaflet.heat](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.heat) plugin written by the Leaflet author, which does animate during zoom. The behavior is different from `heatmap.js`, but may suit your purposes. GeoJSON layers, however, should animate unless the map's [animation options](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-zoomanimation) are turned off. Do the map background tiles animate on zoom?

Comment: Thank you very much! I will consider using Leaflet.heat. I am using a GeoJSON baselayer (no tiles / tile server currently) for the basemap. It does not work out well with the leaflet zoom animation.